# Scroll in a PDF in an <object> tag in mobile safari?

Tags: html, pdf, mobile-safari

Is it possible to scroll a PDF embedded with the `<object>` tag in mobile safari?

Comment: Did you try it to embed a iframe and put the <object> tag into the iframe html file?
I searched for a solution but I've found no really helpful notes. You could also try http://pdfobject.com. I only have an IPhone simulator. Maybe if Adobe Reader is installed on your IPhone this could work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use PhoneGap and the ChildBrowser plugin, opening the document over the webapp in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

try 2 fingers. That works on iframes so it should do it on objects.

If this does work you will have to work with touchstart javascript events and scroll it via javascript :).